# Parse indented list into boolean tree

Tags: php, parsing, tree, indentation

I have a piece of text like the following

```
foo
and foo2
and bar
    or something
    and somethingElse
        or somethingElse2
        or somethingElse3
and baz
    or godknows
    or godknows2
```

This should be interpreted as:

```
(
            foo
            && foo2
    && (bar || (something && (somethingElse || somethingElse2 || somethingElse 3)))
    && (baz || godknows || godknows2)
)
```

At the moment I'm reading line by line. I know that I need to measure the indentation and parse the expression of the next line in order to figure out the expression that the current line belongs too, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that usefully without consuming the next line too.

It seems like the kind of problem which has a recursive solution, but it's escaping me.

The input format isn't fixed, I just want to be able to turn a relatively readable expression into a tree of booleans, so if you can answer with a more suitable format which is still readable, please do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python, which uses this style of indentation, does its parsing by maintaining a stack of indentation levels.  Upon seeing a new line, it determines whether it has been indented from the previous line by seeing whether the current depth has increased.  If so, Python pretends that there was an invisible symbol called "INDENT" that was inserted into the input stream.  It then pushes the new depth onto the stack.

If the indentation decreases, Python repeatedly pops the stack and pretends that an invisible symbol called "DEDENT" was inserted into the input stream until the indentation level matches the value on the stack.

You could probably adapt this approach very easily here by replacing "INDENT" and "DEDENT" with ( and ).  You would need to do a minor transformation afterwards by making sure that the ( token was inserted before the previous variable, but I'd expect this isn't too hard.

With that change, you should be able to parse this extremely easily.  For example, the script

```
A
and B
    or C
       and D
or E
```

Would transform into

```
A and (B or (C and D))) or E
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Pressed enter too early on my previous comment, but the idea the extra invisible token does sound perfect, I'll give it a go, thanks!